# Eliminating certain values from mean calculation in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean of the following sample dataset:

```
bogie-n bypass-n    0.00304367004111
flask-n bypass-n    0.00298246799918
faggot-n    sprayer-n   0.00507314183347
bypass-n    sprayer-n   0.00136494481917
sprayer-n   sprayer-n   1.0
```

I want to remove any value that is equal to 1 or equal to 0 from the calculation of the mean.
I have written the following code to do so:

```
with open(infile) as f:
    cols = [float(row.split("\t")[2]) for row in f.readlines()]
    for col in cols:
        if col == 1 or col == 0:
            pass
        else:
            normalizedDataEuc = float(sum(cols))/float(len(cols))
            output = infile + "\t" + str(normalizedDataEuc) + "\n"
            print output
```

This code successfully calculates the mean of the entire dataset (which in the case of the sample data above is `0.202492845`), however it fails to calculate the mean of the dataset when excluding the value of 1, which would be `0.202492845`.

I tried to implement a double condition which the `col` variable to satisfy, but it does not appear to be doing so, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your double condition works well (as you can see when you put some print statements in there); the problem is that in each iteration of your `for` loop, you calculate the mean of the *entire* `cols` list nonetheless.

Instead, you should filter the `cols` list to remove the `1` and `0` values and then calculate the mean for that filtered list (just these two lines, without the loop):

```
>>> filtered = [col for col in cols if col not in [0, 1]]
>>> sum(filtered) / float(len(filtered))
0.00311605617323
```

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.explainmydata.com/2012/07/expensive-lessons-in-python-performance.html

"Wes McKinney is a genius. If you're implementing anything Wes McKinney has already put in his library pandas, just stop. His code is faster, more robust, and more likely to be correct than anything you're about to write. Want rolling window aggregators? Use pandas. Need to handle missing data? Use pandas. Are you writing some sort of unbelievably ugly hack which attempts to implement joins and group-by's over NumPy arrays but actually manages to spend 3 hours computing a subtly incorrect result? (I have done this). Jesus Christ, just stop and use pandas."

I concur with this. Just Use Pandas. It's pointless to redo what has been done before and by a lot more people and optimized for performance.

Solution:

```
import pandas as pd

s="""bogie-n bypass-n    0.00304367004111
     ...: flask-n bypass-n    0.00298246799918
     ...: faggot-n    sprayer-n   0.00507314183347
     ...: bypass-n    sprayer-n   0.00136494481917
     ...: sprayer-n   sprayer-n   1.0"""

lines = [x.split() for x in s.split('\n')]

lines
Out[152]:
[['bogie-n', 'bypass-n', '0.00304367004111'],
 ['flask-n', 'bypass-n', '0.00298246799918'],
 ['faggot-n', 'sprayer-n', '0.00507314183347'],
 ['bypass-n', 'sprayer-n', '0.00136494481917'],
 ['sprayer-n', 'sprayer-n', '1.0']]

df = pd.DataFrame(lines)

df
Out[154]:
           0          1                 2
0    bogie-n   bypass-n  0.00304367004111
1    flask-n   bypass-n  0.00298246799918
2   faggot-n  sprayer-n  0.00507314183347
3   bypass-n  sprayer-n  0.00136494481917
4  sprayer-n  sprayer-n               1.0



df[2] = df[2].astype(float)

df
Out[163]:
           0          1         2
0    bogie-n   bypass-n  0.003044
1    flask-n   bypass-n  0.002982
2   faggot-n  sprayer-n  0.005073
3   bypass-n  sprayer-n  0.001365
4  sprayer-n  sprayer-n  1.000000



df[df[2] != 1.0]
Out[164]:
          0          1         2
0   bogie-n   bypass-n  0.003044
1   flask-n   bypass-n  0.002982
2  faggot-n  sprayer-n  0.005073
3  bypass-n  sprayer-n  0.001365
```

Comment: Is this supposed to answer the question? If so, at least provide a hint to the exact Pandas module that already provides this "no ones or zeros mean" functionality.

Comment: @tobias_k: just plain DataFrame. This is 101 in Pandas, any tutorial covers such stuff. Anyway, I added (draft of) solution above.